# Apache NodeJS phpmyadmin https

Tags: mysql, node.js, apache, phpmyadmin

I am redirecting everything from http to https using;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Redirect permanent / https://secure.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

To get to nodejs, I am using ProxyPass:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
ProxyPass / http://localhost:2400/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:2400/
...
</VirtualHost>
```

So now when I go to https://secure.mydomain.com/, I see my nodejs app.

What I cannot do is get to https://secure.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin

I have tried to include the default phpmyadmin apache.conf but with no results.  Everything was working well before ssl.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

You have to exclude `/phpmyadmin` from reverse proxy setting.

Add

```
ProxyPass /phpmyadmin !
```

before all `ProxyPass` setting.

You can find more explanation in documentation:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass